# showing a div on mouseover and having it till we click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show a div on mouseover/hover on top of a button and the div which is shown should be able to clickble and persistent even if I move out of button into the div that is shown. but this should be hidden when we move out of the whole area.

I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
var mouseX;    
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
});

$(".circle-button-small").hover(function () {
    mouseX = mouseX;
    mouseY = mouseY - 100;
    $('.theme-hover').css({
        'top': mouseY,
        'left': mouseX
    }).show('slow');
});

$(".circle-button-small").mouseout(function () {
    if ($(".theme-hover").mouseenter()) {
        $('.theme-hover').css({
            'top': mouseY,
            'left': mouseX
        }).show('slow');
    } else {
        $('.theme-hover').hide('slow');
    }
});
```

**Update**

```
$(".circle-button-small").hover(
    function () {
        mouseX = mouseX;
        mouseY = mouseY - 100;
        $('.theme-hover').css({
            'top': mouseY,
            'left': mouseX
        }).show('slow');
    }, 
    function () {
        $('.theme-hover').hide('slow');
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2oj799u/6/

**Update:**
solution posted by jbyrne2007 was helpful but that is a workaround. I need something like the one mentioned in comments below,

When I hover I need the "theme-hover" to appear near the mouse pointer, and also when I exit circle-button, if not into the "theme-hover", "theme-hover" should be hidden, else if I enter "theme-hover" it should be still visible... the solution above is like a work around..

Comment: jQuery hover function takes 2 params: in and out functions: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: I am quite new to Jquery.... I use circular buttons so when ever I hover it sort of beat, shuffles between show and hide most of the times.

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net/ please.

Comment: It isn't necessary to provide both _in_ and _out_ functions. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp)

Comment: will give the fiddle sooner

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u2oj799u/6/ @Zentoaku

Comment: Please try to explain a little better what you want. i.E. "move out of the whole area." - what do you mean by 'whole area'?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/u2oj799u/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im a little unclear as to what your end result should be but take a look at
[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2oj799u/9/)

```
$(".main-area").mouseleave(function () {
$('.theme-hover').hide('slow');
});
```

I've moved the div .theme-hover inside the .main-area so when you move over to click it wont disappear.

I also added this to the style of .theme-hover

```
cursor:pointer;
```

makes it a little more user friendly.

Again I assumed you wanted the div with "Hey" in to appear when you click so I put the click in there as well.

```
 $(".theme-hover").click(function () {
        $('.overlay').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: @jbyme2007 ... thanks a lot.. that was the same that I wanted.. thanks a ton :)

Comment: When I hover I need the "theme-hover" to appear near the mouse pointer, and also when I exit circle-button, if not into the "theme-hover", "theme-hover" should be hidden, else if I enter "theme-hover" it should be still visible... the solution above is like a work around.. can we achieve what I described in this post ?

Comment: could you please help on this above.. @jbyrne2007